# Recursive manipulation of vector elements

Tags: r

I have a vector `a` and want to multiply each element recursively with `b`, without using a loop.

```
a <- rep(0, 10)
a[1] <- 1
b <- 2

# with a loop
for (i in 2:length(a)) a[i] <- a[i-1] * b
```

I would be grateful for hints on how to tackle this without using a loop.

Comment: In general recursion is difficult to vectorize.  See here for ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153586/can-i-vectorize-a-calculation-which-depends-on-previous-elements  It would help if you could explain why you want to avoid the loop (speed?), and if this is the actual problem you want to solve (as sometimes problems can be re-conceived to avoid recursion entirely).

Comment: Thanks for you comment and the link. Speed is not really an issue. It is more a matter of curiosity. I have been thinking about it for some time and was wondering if there is away to vectorize it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you can't do this without an explicit loop.  In this specific case, you can use the implicit loop provided by `cumprod`:

```
a <- rep(2, 10)
a[1] <- 1
cumprod(a)
#  [1]   1   2   4   8  16  32  64 128 256 512
```

Comment: It's probably worthwhile noting that `cumprod()` will be much faster too since it is a `.Primitive()`...my tests indicate about 4x faster than the native `for loop`, though only 1.2x if you compile both functions with `cmpfun()` from package `compiler`. +1

Answer (score 5):

For general recursive series of the form:

```
y[i] = x[i] + f[1]*y[i-1] + ... + f[p]*y[i-p]
```

you can use the `filter` function. In your case, you have `x[i] = 0`, `f[1] = 2` and `f[i] = 0` for `i > 1`. This translates into:

```
filter(rep(0,10), 2, method="recursive", init=1/2)
# Time Series:
# Start = 1 
# End = 10 
# Frequency = 1 
#  [1]   1   2   4   8  16  32  64 128 256 512
```

After you learn how to use it, which is not always obvious the first time, `filter` is very powerful and efficient. But maybe it is overkill for your geometric case here.

Comment: How would you generalize filter to be used in the general case?

Answer (score 3):

The exponent function `^` is vectorized, so quite simply:

```
2^(0:9)
# [1]   1   2   4   8  16  32  64 128 256 512
```

which you might also want to write

```
2^seq(from=0, to=9)
```

For long vectors, I am pretty sure @JoshuaUlrich's method will be much faster, but this one is certainly very compact. You also said you were not particularly concerned about speed.