# How to trim an R vector?

Tags: r, vectorization

I have the following sorted vector:

```
> v
 [1] -1  0  1  2  4  5  2  3  4  5  7  8  5  6  7  8 10 11
```

How can I remove the -1, 0, and 11 entries *without looping over the whole vector*, either with a user loop or implicitly with a language keyword? That is, I want to trim the vector at each *edge* and only at each edge, such that the sorted sequence is within my min,max parameters 1 and 10. The solution should assume that the vector is sorted to avoid checking every element.

This kind of solutions can come handy in vectorized operations for very large vectors, when we  want to use the items in the vector as indexes in another object. For one application see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200667/how-can-i-vectorize-access-to-neighbour-vector-elements-in-r).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the previous solutions implicitly check every element of the vector. As @Robert Kubrick points out, this does not take advantage of the fact that the vector is already sorted.

To take advantage of the sorted nature of the vector, you can use binary search (through `findInterval`) to find the start and end indexes without looking at every element:

```
n<-1e9
v<--3:(n+3)
system.time(a <- v [v>=1 & v <=n]) # 68 s
system.time(b <- v[do.call(seq,as.list(findInterval(c(1,n),v)))]) # 15s
identical(a,b) # TRUE
```

It is a little clumsy, and there is [some discussion](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/General-binary-search-td3426478.html) that the binary search in `findInterval` may not be entirely efficient, but the general idea is there.

---

As was pointed out in the comments, the above only works when the index is in the vector. Here is a function that I think will work:

```
in.range <- function(x, lo = -Inf, hi = +Inf) {
   lo.idx <- findInterval(lo, x, all.inside = TRUE)
   hi.idx <- findInterval(hi, x)
   lo.idx <- lo.idx + x[lo.idx] >= lo
   x[seq(lo.idx, hi.idx)]
}

system.time(b <- in.range(v, 1, n) # 15s
```

Comment: Definitely faster for a sorted vector, but this will work iff the min/max elements are included in the original vector, as @flodel pointed out.

Comment: I tried the `head`/`tail` method and another approach and added the benchmarks to my original question, if you're curious.

Comment: @flodel I like the edit. My function was ugly. Is the `all.inside` argument vectorized? You might be able to do `findInterval(c(lo,hi), x, all.inside = c(TRUE,FALSE))`

Answer (score 13):

To include elements in a vector by index:

```
v [2:10]
```

to exclude certain elements

```
v [-c (1, 11) ]
```

to only include a certain range:

```
v <- v [v>=1 & v <=10]
```

---

If I'm allowed to assume that, like in your example, the number of elements to be trimmed << the number of elements in the vector, then I think I can beat the binary search:

```
> n<-1e8
> v<--3:(n+3)
> 
> min <- 1
> max <- length(v)
> 
> calcMin <- function(v, minVal){
+   while(v[min] < minVal){
+       min <- min + 1
+   }
+   min
+ }
> 
> calcMax <- function(v, maxVal){
+   while(v[max] > maxVal){
+       max <- max - 1
+   }
+   max
+ }
> 
> #Compute the min and max indices and create a sequence
> system.time(a <- v[calcMin(v, 1):calcMax(v,n)])
   user  system elapsed 
  1.030   0.269   1.298 
> 
> #do a binary search to find the elements (as suggested by @nograpes)
> system.time(b <- v[do.call(seq,as.list(findInterval(c(1,n),v)))])
   user  system elapsed 
  2.208   0.631   2.842 
> 
> #use negative indexing to remove elements
> system.time(c <- v[-c(1:(calcMin(v, 1)-1), (calcMax(v,n)+1):length(v))])
   user  system elapsed 
  1.449   0.256   1.704 
> 
> #use head and tail to trim the vector
> system.time(d <- tail(head(v, n=(calcMax(v,n)-length(v))), n=-calcMin(v, 1)+1))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.994   0.877   3.871 
> 
> identical(a, b)
[1] TRUE
> identical(a, c)
[1] TRUE
> identical(a, d)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: +1 - The last one is what the OP is asking for. It is also the fastest solution. (edit: I replaced `&&` with `&`)

Comment: +1 your answer is the right one, mine were  alternatives to yours :D

Comment: @flodel Just curious, how is this faster? It doesn't have any knowledge of the sorted nature of the vector.

Comment: `% in%` must compare each integer in your range separately. "v == 1? v==2? v==3?..." whereas `<` and `>` can compare in just two ( vectorized) calls. Either would be fine for a small range, but you wouldn't run % in% on a set with a million elements.

Comment: @flodel I think OP is actually looking to make use of the fact that the vector is already sorted, which this solution does not take advantage of. I have posted my own answer below.

Comment: @nograpes: I challenge you to find something faster. Not that it is impossible, but this is short, vectorized, and has O(n) complexity.

Comment: @flodel I think I did. Check my answer which I posted below.

Comment: @JeffAllen Indeed, if the number of elements to be trimmed is very small, then binary search can be wasteful. Maybe if the binary search was started at the ends of the vector rather than the middle, it would improve the time over simply looping through the first few.

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to do it, here's some:

```
> v <- -1:11 # creating your vector
> v[v %in% 1:10]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> setdiff(v, c(-1,0,11))
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> intersect(v, 1:10)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Two more options, not so elegant.

```
> na.omit(match(v, 1:10))
> na.exclude(match(v, 1:10))
```

Comment: Algorithmically, set inclusion is much slower than checking for a couple inequalities. Imagine if the boundaries were not `1` and `10` but `-1e8` and `1e8`... @Robert, Jilber, agstudy, I urge you to reconsider. Jeff's the right answer.

Comment: @flodel what you are asking for is already answered in Jeff Allen's post, isn't it?? `v [v>=1 & v <=10]` or more generally `v [v>= lower bound & v <= upper bound]`

Comment: Yes and I am trying to bring attention to it.

Comment: So we can ask the OP (@Robert Kubrick) to mark Jeff Allen's answer as the correct one :D, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "I urge you to reconsider. Jeff's the right answer".

Comment: @flodel You are correct. In facts my problem is exactly for a very large vector of indexes that I need to apply to another object containing millions of entry. I added more information to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `%in%` also :

```
 vv <- c(-1,  0  ,1  ,2  ,4  ,5,  2  ,3  ,4,  5,  7  ,8,  5,  6,  7,  8, 10, 11)
 vv[vv %in% 1:10]

 [1]  1  2  4  5  2  3  4  5  7  8  5  6  7  8 10
```