# Can you provide a specific situation illustrating when a loop in R could be preferred to an apply function?

Tags: r, for-loop

Can you please provide a specific situation illustrating when a for loop might work more effectively than the more commonly cited apply suite of solutions?

Comment: You might be able to edit this into a reasonable question.  Please try.

Answer (score 1):

If the results of the previous computation are used in the next computation, it is appropriate to use a `for` loop, since this behavior is difficult to replicate with `lapply` (you would have to use something like `Reduce`). R is not necessarily slow with `for` loops, merely with memory allocation (which is easy to get wrong with `for` loops). See [Chapter 2 of the R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: Can you given an example that can't be done in `lapply`?

Comment: @John - this question comes to mind: [Can I vectorize a calculation which depends on previous elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153586/can-i-vectorize-a-calculation-which-depends-on-previous-elements)

Comment: If the function passed to `lapply` must contain `<<-`, `lapply` is not appropriate.

Comment: OK, about <<-, but that's a different answer. And, `lapply` is not vectorization. It's used to express a loop in a way that works better when you're trying to vectorize by encouraging compact loops where necessary combined with real vectorized R. Chapter 2 of Inferno is about growing objects. You can grow them in `lapply` and not grow them in `for`. It's relatively unrelated.

Comment: @Matthew Lundberg, why would (implicitly) global assignments with `for` be better than explicitly global assignments with `<<-` and `lapply`? (Just asking. I wouldn't say lapply is better, but having to use `<<-` wouldn't stop me using `lapply`. I would use it if it's conveinient. In a sense, `for` always does a `<<-` as it always adds a global variable named at your choice (often `i`) possibly overwriting existing objects with the same name.)