# Vectorization with precedent index

Tags: r, vectorization

Trying to vectorize in R, I often found myself blocked when coding those kind of 'for' loop:

```
  vector = 1:10
  cumulativeSum = vector[1]
  for (i in seq_along(vector)[-1]) {
    cumulativeSum[i] = cumulativeSum[i-1] + vector[i]
  }
```

The need of a precedent index that you cannot know in advance force me into using a third function or into rcpp to still avoid those cumbersome 'for' loops.
In this exemple, we could use cumsum() to avoid this. I also use the diff() function often.

Is there some other functions that are often usefull in those situations? Is there a general way of avoiding the issue.

---

First example:

```
c[i] =  ( a[i]*s[i] + ( (c[i-1]*w[i])/l )) / (
  (  ((w[i]-w[i-1])+w[i]) / l ) + o[i] )
```

Second example: 
Obtaining an increasing vector

```
vector = c(1,2,3,4,5,3,9,10)
for (i in rev(1:(length(vector )-1))){
  if (vector [i] > vector [i+1]) vector [i] = vector [i+1]
}
# c(1,2,3,3,3,3,9,10)
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question (maybe needs to be more concrete?) but you can replace your loop with `cumsum(vector)`.

Comment: Something slightly more generalisable would be `sapply(1:10, function(x) sum(vector[1:x]))`

Comment: Sure it is what I explained. But i wonder if there is not a more general solution because right i have more somthing like that:
c[i] =  ( a[i]*s[i] + ( (c[i-1]*w[i])/l )) / (
  (  ((w[i]-w[i-1])+w[i]) / l ) + o[i] )

Comment: I agree with @snoram; a more specific example would help. There is also `Vectorize` that might be helpful.

Comment: @pepece Please don't post code in comments; better to edit your original post to include additional details. Can you also make your second example self-contained, i.e. include code, sample data and expected output?

Comment: I don't think there is a generic way to vectorise a loop that depends on a previous output value. Sometimes you just have to deal with it. Other useful functions are `cumsum` `cummax` `cummin` `stats::filter` (or just`filter` if you don't load the tidyverse), and the `zoo` package's `roll*` functions. Also, this is pretty much repeating this discussion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153586/vectorize-a-product-calculation-which-depends-on-previous-elements

Comment: Thanks, it is a good beginning

Comment: I would bet that if you will make your "tougher" problem reproducible and explain the context well you'll receive some interesting answers from which you can pick up principles to apply in similar situations.

Comment: It is just some raw data. and the calculation is representing some physics.
I am affraid that the rest is confidential. I don't think I can help much further. I will try to find another example.